# "Lorentz-invariant" Morse theory possible?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Hi,

I hope filing this under "Morse theory" is correct.

For the "abstract tensor" approach to knot theory you need:
a) a 4D tensor to emulate particle interaction,
b) a 2D tensor to emulate pair creation/annihilation. 
(I formulate it in Feynman diagram terms.)
You don't actually need
c) a particle propagator since this is the delta function.

Now you can rotate a knot by 90 degrees and you can rotate
a Feynman diagram by 90 degrees, but you can't "rotate
Morse theory by 90 degrees"! And I find this extremely
annoying. A "nice" abstract tensor Sabcd emulating a
crossing should have *exactly* the same symmetry properties
as a crossing, i.e. invariance under all 180 degree
rotations. And for the pair tensor Pab likewise Pab=Pba (1),
and the delta function should be Pab too, instead.

One *can* introduce "gauges" and use an equivalent tensor
formulation, using Pab for left and right turns, 
but (1) gets you into problems in no time and I never was
able to find a "Lorentz-invariant" tensor set. 
The interesting solutions are even CPT-invariant (for intuitive 
interpretations of C, P, and T for abstract tensors, I even
have charge and baryon number conservation automagically), 
but T(S)=S^-1 should hold (where I only can get T(S)=S for my 
solutions).

Am I doing something wrong or is Morse theory (or more precise,
Kauffman's abstract tensor approach) symmetry-breaking by nature?

Hauke

Comment: I am not really sure I understand what the question is. Can you say something more precise than "rotate Morse theory by 90 degrees"? 

Comment: @Qiaochu: Maybe this is what Hauke is trying to say.  One way to search for knot invariants is the following.  Any knot (nice map from S^1 to R^3=(x,y,z)) can be perturbed just a little bit so that (1) its projection to R^2=(x,y) has nothing worse than transverse double points (i.e. so that it projects to a "knot diagram"), and (2) its projection to R=(x) has nothing worse than nondegenerate cusps (i.e. its "height" function x is Morse).  Then I can chop up the diagram into pieces that look like: cups, caps, crossings. (continued)

Comment: (continuation) Two diagrams represent the same knot if they are related by: (1) Reidemeister moves, (2) cap-cup creation/annihilation, (3) switching the heights of distant caps and cups. So what Hauke wants to do is find "Feynman rules", which interpret a cup as a (0,2)-tensor for some vector space V, a cap as some (2,0)-tensor, and a crossing as a (2,2)-tensor, and roughly-vertical lines as the identity map (a (1,1)-tensor). These tensors have to satisfy some quadratic and cubic relations, which look like they overdetermine the tensors.  But solutions exist, coming from quantum groups. (cont)

Comment: (continuation) So, then, I think that Hauke is just bemoaning the fact that the invariance under Morse and Reidemeister moves must be added in by hand/fiat --- the decomposition of a knot into pieces that can be interpreted as tensors is not manifestly invariant.  Of course, that's because it _isn't_ invariant --- Morse theory is a calculational tool, and requires a choice of height function and understanding of how different choices are related, just like the Reidemeister moves are.  When Hauke says "Lorentz invariance" he's talking about the SO(2) that acts on knot diagrams.

Comment: THX, Theo, you summed up the setup nicely. 

But it's not the *decomposition* as such which is
the problem: OK, if you rotate a knot by 90 degrees, 
the pieces will be different. But if I decompose
nonstandardly, i.e. assigning a tensor to ALL
turns < > ^ v and crossings °/. .\°, instead of letting
< and > be the delta function (forgive my ASCII),
this is gauge-equivalent to the standard approach.
(If < = Pab, > = Qab, °/. = Rabcd, then the
standard crossing tensor is sum(Pai*Ribcj*Qjd).)
So < > swaps with ^ v and °/. with .\°, and *the
tensor itself* should reflect that symmetry. (cont)



Comment: It doesn't even for the Jones polynome:
just look at the diagonal of it's corresponding
S-matrix, it's something like x y 0 x. 
Rotating the crossing by 180 deg, it stays
the same, but the tensor is now x 0 y x. 
Thus I would like a reformulation where
the tensor diagonal is x y y x or suchlike,
but even with my nonstandard setup adding
some degrees of freedom for < >, I failed.
So, why can't the tensor emulating the
crossing have the same geometric symmetries
as the crossing?

Hauke

Comment: I am failing to see where Lorentz symmetry appears anywhere in the question.  In particular, there do not appear to be any manifolds equipped with a metric of signature $(n,1)$ or $(1,n)$, except perhaps the knot itself (when $n=0$).

Comment: This example is even clearer: Take some Morse diagram
and rotate it by 180 deg in the plane. Caps and cups
swap (and it's easy to choose a gauge where cap=cup),
and all crossings don't change. But in the tensor
emulation, Sabcd->Sdcba. Even for the Jones polynomial,
Sabcd != Sdcba. (In all gauges, I think.) What magic
happens that the value of the knot doesn't change?
(OK, rhetorical question :-) But you see my problem -
Sabcd=Sdcba would be far more intuitive.)

Hauke